# Remove Duplicates from Sorted Linklist C programming

Tags: c, pointers

```
struct ListNode* deleteDuplicates(struct ListNode* head)
{
    if(head==NULL)
        return NULL;
    else if(head->next==NULL)
        return head;
    struct ListNode* r=head,*q=NULL;
    while(r!=NULL)
    {
        q=r;
        r=r->next;
        if(q->val==r->val)
        {
            while(q->val==r->val&&r!=NULL)
            {
                r=r->next;
            }
            q->next=r;
        }
    }
    return head;
}
```

The line `(q->val==r->val)` shows runtime error:

> member access within null pointer of type 'struct ListNode'.

How to correct this error?

Comment: Hint: operands of `&&` are computed *left to right*.

Answer (score 0):

One comment :

```
    r=r->next; // if r is the last one
            // r becomes null here
if(q->val==r->val)
{
```